# In AS3, can I make text of input text field of more than 2 are same?

Tags: actionscript-3

It perfectly works when instance name and var name are same in Flash 8, but I don't know how I can do it in Animate CC 2018... I'm okay if you just give me a fla file.

Thank you for understanding my poor English.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLcpH.png)

Comment: There's no such thing as variable name (one that allows linking multiple text fields) in AS3. You need to subscribe to **Event.CHANGE** to each one of the **TextField**s in order to cross-sync them all when user types anything into any of them.

Comment: Thank You!!! It Worked! Have a Nice Day!!!